# Passing Arugments( perform calculations from a return result of a diffrent contract

Tags: function, arguments, solidity, contract

I'm trying to perform a calculation in contract B

```
contract B {

function add () external pure returns (uint) 
{
uint public date = date ;
uint public cycle = 28 ;

    uint sum = date + cycle ;

    return 'sum'; 
}

}
```

Then calling this function in contract A to recive the return 'sum ' that I have in B

```
contract A {
    // This is for calculationg ore ovulation 
    address addressB; 

    function setAddressB (address __addressB) external {
        
        addressB= __addressB; 
    }
 function calladd()external view returns(uint ) 
 {

    B npd = B(addressB); 
    return npd.add ();
    uint n =9; 

    addition = npd +n ; 
  }

}
```

Then add 9 to the result.

To get the return results in contract B and add call it in contract a and perform calculations